# golang source code plan9 asm

Tags: assembly, go, plan-9

When I read the source code from golang src,then I can not understand the asm code,such as:

```
// void gogo(Gobuf*)
// restore state from Gobuf; longjmp
TEXT runtime·gogo(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-8
MOVQ 8(SP), BX // gobuf
MOVQ gobuf_g(BX), DX
MOVQ 0(DX), CX // make sure g != nil
get_tls(CX)
MOVQ DX, g(CX)
MOVQ gobuf_sp(BX), SP // 从 G.sched.sp 恢复 SP 寄存器
MOVQ gobuf_ret(BX), AX
MOVQ gobuf_ctxt(BX), DX
MOVQ $0, gobuf_sp(BX) // clear to help garbage collector
MOVQ $0, gobuf_ret(BX)
MOVQ $0, gobuf_ctxt(BX)
MOVQ gobuf_pc(BX), BX // 将 G.sched.pc，也就是 goroutine 函数地址压⼊入 BX。
JMP BX
```

I have no idea about the define the function name why with(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-8 etc. and what does this line "MOVQ 8(SP), BX" means.

Comment: Looks vaguely like 16bit x86 assembler.  In that case, `MOVQ 8(SP), BX` could mean move the value that is 8 bytes from the stack pointer into the register named bx.

Comment: You probably want this: https://golang.org/doc/asm
Further reading on the weird register naming and platform specific nonsense: http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/asm.html

Comment: 0(SP) means the first local variable and the 4(SP) means the second variable. this is somebody told me.I dowt know wether is correct?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Yes, the number is the offset in bytes from the address. So 4(SP) is only the second variable if the first variable is 4-bytes long.

Comment: @Jsor this code MOVQ 8(SP), BX. assume the machine word is 64bits then 8(SP) means the second local variable. why the second local variable is gobuf and what does the first local variable? thinks

Comment: I don't know, this isn't a normal function, it's a runtime builtin of some sort. In go we read inputs off the frame pointer (FP), the stack pointer (SP) grows in the negative direction and is used for calling other functions, so it appears it's actually reading something like the first variable on the call stack for the calling function. I'm not 100% sure, so not an answer. I'm guessing it's probably reading a function pointer or something to schedule concurrent function calls?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd It isn't. It's Plan 9 assembly syntax. `AX` refers to `al`, `ax`, `eax`, or `rax` depending on the suffix of the instruction. So Plan 9 `MOVQ 8(SP),BX` is equal to AT&T `mov 8(%esp),%ebx`.

Comment: (The previous comment should be amended to mean `mov 8(%rsp), %rbx` but it's too late to change it.